# Resolve Symbols in Datagrip

Tags: sql, oracle, datagrip

I have a DWH with a few schemas. I always have to use tables and views from different schemas to combine them for new views. This is done in a REPORT schema that has all the synonyms to almost all the tables and views in the other schemas. All those tables and views also have privileges granted to REPORT.

Whenever I make a reference to a different schema then REPORT, Datagrip is not able to resolve that reference, stating that it is "Unable to resolve symbol.."

I am not sure, whether this is needed for the referencing or not, but I have database connections in the project to all schemas.

Let's say, I need col1 and col2 from a table srctable located in a schema DATA. I do all the code in the schema REPORT.

I have tried code like

```
SELECT 
  col1,
  col2
FROM
  srctable
```

And also

```
SELECT 
  col1,
  col2
FROM
  DATA.srctable
```

Since I get the data from the query, everything seems to be set up right. But I want to utilise the power of Datagrip and it is annoying I can not get the references to work.

Comment: You might try creating a bug ticket in their issue tracking system: (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE)

Comment: It should be fixed in the current EAP of 2022.2 after the introducing of Resolve Modes feature.
https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/nextversion/

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose destination schemas in database tree for completion to work.

[image: resolve]